# Django form not showing up in template

Tags: python, django

My problem is not showing up form in the Django template.
I'm using python 3.7.6
Django 3.2
Here is my code

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from tasks.models import Task, TaskType


class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                           required=True,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    input_image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control-file'}))
    task_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TaskType.objects.name.all(), widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['name', 'input_image', 'task_type']
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from tasks.forms import TaskForm
def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'submit-task' in request.POST:
        task_form = TaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if task_form.is_valid():
            task_form.save()
            return redirect(to='dashboard')

    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', {'task_form': task_form})
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
              {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen-lg-down">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <!-- Modal Header -->
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Upload your image</h4>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn-close"
                      data-dismiss="modal"
                    ></button>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Modal body -->
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                    <label class="">Task name</label>
                    {{task_form.name}}                                  
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                          <option selected>Choose your model</option>
                          {{task_form.task_type}}
                        </select>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <span class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-file">
                            Browse… {{task_form.image_input}}
                          </span>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly />
                      </div>
                      <img id="img-upload" />
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Modal footer -->
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-secondary"
                      data-dismiss="modal"
                    >
                      Close
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit-task">
                      Save changes
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

So, in the template, the form is not showing up. Please help me to fix it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```py
def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'submit-task' in request.POST:
        task_form = TaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        ...

    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', {'task_form': task_form})
```

I pretty sure that you want to return `dashboard.html` on `GET` method,
however `task_form` is creating only when `POST` method. In other words `task_form` does not exists.

You should define it before using:

```py
def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'submit-task' in request.POST:
        task_form = TaskForm(...)
        ...
    else:
        task_form = TaskForm(...) # task form defined for non POST methods

    # or place it here
    # task_form = TaskForm(...) # task form defined for non POST methods

    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', {'task_form': task_form})
```

Comment: I have tried to return `dashboard.html` on `GET` method, but the template still does not exist. I don't know where is my error.

Comment: @TrầnQuangThìn Error is: You should define `task_form` before using it

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/SwxqjT1) I have added but it's not showing up.

Comment: @TrầnQuangThìn ok, then explain you problem clearly: 1. do you see any errors? 2. `form not showing up` and `template still does not exist` are absolutely different problems. What means `not showing up`? 3. Your `dashboard.html` doesn't have `<html></html>` tags at all. Is it just part of page or completely not correct full page? 4. What is Django logs? etc etc

Comment: By the way, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view) is how to use forms. `Form` instance is using as is {{ task_form }} to automatically fill template. You trying to use only form fields: `{{task_form.field_name}}`. `Form` object is not necessary for this usage.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing in your code is you are passing an instance for a create method but the instance does not exist when you didn't create the record yet, the other problem is you are not supporting the get method.
there is an example :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from tasks.forms import TaskForm
from .models import Task


def create_task(request):
    instance = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if instance:
            task_form = TaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        else:
            task_form = TaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if task_form.is_valid():
            task_form.save()
            return redirect(to='dashboard')
        return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', {'task_form': task_form})
    else:
        if instance:
            task_form = TaskForm(instance=request.user)
        else:
            task_form = TaskForm()

    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', {'task_form': task_form})
```