# Django dropdown menu with nested classes not showing form-field in template

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, drop-down-menu

Django (4.1.4): I´m trying to display a dropdown-menu for changing the status of "MyModel" in a table using a form, bot the fields are not shown in the template. I also tried to use javascript to enable the change of the status dynamically. Both approaches failed.
Changing the status trough the admin page is working properly, as well as displaying the current status in the template.
The project is based on the Visual Studio Django Webapp template. The following stylesheets and scripts are included:
bootstrap 3.0.0,
jquery-1.10.2
jquery-2.2.4
ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.7

1. Is MyModel correctly structured and are choices properly used?
2. Where are the mistakes? I assume, they might be in the forms.py-file, but I cannot find them. Following many tutorials, none of them worked for me. Also checking other posts did not help me further, like this one:
   [Django form not showing up in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821818/django-form-not-showing-up-in-template)

models.py:

```
import uuid

class MyModel(models.Model):      
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Name')

        class Status(models.Choices):
                IN_ARBEIT = 'Modell in Arbeit'
                BEREIT = 'Bereit'
                DOKUMENTATION = 'Dokumentation'
                FERTIGGESTELLT = 'Fertiggestellt'
                ZU_AKTUALISIEREN = 'Zu aktualisieren'
                REVISION = 'In Revision'

        status = models.CharField(
                max_length=30, 
                choices=Status.choices, 
                default=Status.IN_ARBEIT,
                verbose_name ='Bearbeitungsstatus'
                )
```

I would apprappreciate your help!

1ST approach without javascript:
forms.py:

```
from .models import MyModel
class StatuChoicesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Specify the 'status' field as a ChoiceField with the MyModel.Status choices
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MyModel.Status.choices)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['status']
```

views.py:

```
from .forms import StatusChoicesForm
def change_model_status(request, model_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StatuChoicesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the selected value for the 'status' field
            status = form.cleaned_data['status']
            # Do something with the selected value (e.g. update a model instance)
            model = MyModel.objects.get(id=model_id)
            model.status = status
            model.save()
            return redirect('model_info.html')
        else:
            status_form = StatuChoicesForm()
            
        return render(request, 'models.html', {'status_form': status_form})
```

models.html:

> {% csrf_token %}
>     {{ status_form.as_p }}

2nd approach using javascript/AJAX:

model.js:

```
  // Function to update the status field in the MyModel object
  function updateStatus(status) {
    // Send an AJAX request to the server to update the status field
    $.ajax({
      url: '/update-status/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'status': status},
      success: function(response) {
        // Update the status field in the UI
        $('#current-status').text(status);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }

  // Bind the updateStatus function to the change event of the dropdown menu
  $('#status-dropdown').change(function() {
    var selectedStatus = $(this).val();
    updateStatus(selectedStatus);
  });
```

view.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def update_status(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    # Get the new status from the request data
    new_status = request.POST.get('status')
```

models.html:

```
<!-- Dropdown menu for the Status class -->
<!-- Dropdown menu for the Status class -->
{% block content %}
<select id="status-dropdown" class="form-control">
  {% for status in custom_model.SystemType.choices %}
    <option value="{{ status.0 }}">{{ status.1 }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/model.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your form`s name is StatuChoicesForm, but you imported StatusChoicesForm ("s" is missing) in forms.py. Have you used <form> tag in your template?

Comment: Thank you for your response!
It was really helpfull. However, my fault was to create a seperate view-function which wasn´t called inside my main function which is linked to the html-file in the url-patterns. Since I included the code above into the main view-function, it works. Thanks again!